# Spotcolor bleeds into the surrounding

Tags: color, packages, printing

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`xspotcolor`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/xspotcolor.dtx)

I have a problem using `spotcolor` package.  When using the package for redefining headers, titles, `\emph` etc. the color bleeds into the surrounding.  The behaviour is quite different than the behaviour of `xcolor` package.

I am *guessing* that this is a package problem.  I have contacted the author and he is unable to help as he is out of LaTeX business for years.  Since this is really a small package, is it possible that someone has a peek into it and (in case there is a mistake) corrects it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{spotcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}
\AddSpotColor{PANTONE} {PANTONE3035PC} {PANTONE\SpotSpace 3035\SpotSpace PC} {1 0 0.05 0.72}

% Redefinition of \emph command

\begin{document}

\SetPageColorSpace{PANTONE}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\em{%
  \@nomath\em
  \SpotColor{PANTONE3035PC}{1}
  \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
    \upshape
  \else
    \itshape
  \fi}
\makeatother

The \emph{Pantone colour} spills outside of \slash emph command.

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\em{%
  \@nomath\em
  \color{red}
  \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
    \upshape
  \else
    \itshape
  \fi}
\makeatother

The \emph{normal red} does not.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, note that if you don't want to use `xcolor` but are content with the original `color` package, then you can switch to spot colors just like normal colors, using the `spotcolor` color model.

Try this modified example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{spotcolor}
\usepackage{color}

\NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}
\AddSpotColor{PANTONE} {PANTONE3035PC} {PANTONE\SpotSpace 3035\SpotSpace PC} {1 0 0.05 0.72}

% Redefinition of \emph command

\begin{document}

\SetPageColorSpace{PANTONE}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\em{%
  \@nomath\em
  \color[spotcolor]{PANTONE3035PC,1.0}
  \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
    \upshape
  \else
    \itshape
  \fi}
\makeatother

The \emph{Pantone colour} does no longer spill outside of \verb|\emph| command.

\textcolor[spotcolor]{PANTONE3035PC,0.5}{Lighter shade}.

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\em{%
  \@nomath\em
  \color{red}
  \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
    \upshape
  \else
    \itshape
  \fi}
\makeatother

The \emph{normal red} does neither.

\end{document}
```

The package `xcolor` you are using has some incompatibilities with `spotcolor`.

I've written a package [`xspotcolor`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/xspotcolor.dtx) which combines and stitches both packages together. At the moment it is sitting on the TEX-SX repository waiting to be tested, but hopefully it can go to CTAN soon.

Try it out!

Comment: This answer solves out the problem of spilling, the previous answer the problem of tikz.  But is it also possible to solve *both* problems concomitantly?  (This solution gives "! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model `spot'." when using with tikz)

Comment: @Pygmalion I assume you missed some ingredients when mixing the concoction :-) When I put everything together (code and examples), all went well. I edited this answer to contain the combined code. Over the weekend I'll put this into an extension package for `spotcolor` which can hopefully go on CTAN.

Comment: Now it really works!  (I forgot to replace \SpotColor with \color).  I am looking forward for a new package!

Comment: @pygmalion Please note that I rewrote my answer owing to the fact that I've now made a new package `xspotcolor` from my patches.

Comment: Great!  I'll do testing on my huge file.  For a start, there was an error compiling `xspotcolor.dtx` `! LaTeX Error: File `spotcolorseparation' not found.` (line 701)

Comment: @Pygmalion Thanks! Sorry about the error; you also need to download the file http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/spotcolorseparation.png  On CTAN both will be together.

Comment: I've tested it and works like a charm :)  Again, thanks for your effort.  Just leave me a note when your package becomes available on CTAN.

Comment: Cool! I always had considered it *more than ridiculus* that I could create professional color-print publications with LaTeX and TiKZ. You have done the community a big favor!

Comment: @StephanLehmke I cannot see yout package on CTAN.